# iOS Ad_Hoc Build Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, adhoc

I believe I got the symbolicated version of my crash for my app but not quite sure how to deal with it.  This is what I'm seeing:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39b3f04e __abort + 102
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39b3efe4 abort + 84
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e6dcd2 abort_message + 70
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e866e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x395cbf62 _objc_terminate() + 190
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e841c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e83d28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x395cbe12 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec86f80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec86cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
10  GraphicsServices                0x33bdf65e GSEventRunModal + 134
11  UIKit                           0x315d2168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
12  AppName                         0x000ee932 0xd000 + 923954
13  AppName                         0x000121ac 0xd000 + 20908
```

Can someone offer a bit of insight into this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: this backtrace means 'app crashed because an exception was triggered', and that's all.

Comment: is there a way to find out more? The app works on the device and simulator when ran through xCode, but crashes on the Ad_Hoc release build.

Comment: Plz check out your Ad_Hock provisioning profile try to recreate it sometimes it solves the problem.several times I came across same problem but installing and creating new provisioning profiles solves the issue.

Comment: @Lagoo87 you should integrate a crash reporter framework to receive more info about future crashes (e.g. Testflight, Crashlytics etc.)